# Mysql start failed on AWS Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

All

I Can't start up mysqld on aws.ec2.instance, colude help me?

I don't know why?

```
$ sudo yum install -y mysql mysql-server
$ sudo mysql_install_db
$ sudo service mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

blow is some files to display my env..

/etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under different user or group, 
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

my log (/var/log/mysql.log)

```
120506 10:53:44 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
120506 10:53:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
120506 10:53:44 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120506 10:53:44 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120506 10:53:44 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120506 10:53:44 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120506 10:53:44 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
120506 10:53:44 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120506 10:53:44 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120506 10:53:44 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 48941
120506 10:53:44  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1595675
120506 10:53:44  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
120506 10:53:44  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120506 10:53:45 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120506 10:53:45 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
120506 10:53:45 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
120506 10:53:45 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

if needs any other informations, tell me pleace

Comment: Just belongs on ServerFault. Your MySQL data folder has been trashed, the MySQL table is no longer present. Need to purge and reconfigure from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find file host.frm and check the group and the user that it belongs to.
"errno: 13" means:

```
~$ perror 13
OS error code  13:  Permission denied
```

so it's probably that.
If you don't have that file (that is a table in mysql), you have to regenerate them with:

```
~$ mysql_install_db
```

Cheers,

mazzi.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue many times on multiple AWS servers, main root cause in my cases was lack of space.

So, just free up some space on the server and restart your mysqld and it should start working fine.